# cannot wget from uniprot, what does the ssv3 error mean?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, wget, bioinformatics

EDITED
I am fairly new to bioinformatics, I have a script to download sequence data from uniprot, when I use the wget command however I am getting an error message for some of the weblinks:

```
OpenSSLL error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

So, some of the sequence data downloads (3 in total) and then I get this error message for each of the others.
I am using a virtual box with the ubuntu OS, and so using a bash script.
I have tried installing an updated version of wget but I get a message saying the latest version is installed. Has anyone got any suggestions?

As requested, script is as follows:

```
VAR=$(cat uniprot_id.txt)
URL="https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"
for i in ${VAR}
    do
        echo "(o) Downloading Uniprot entry: ${i}"
        wget ${URL}${i}.fasta
        echo "(o) Done downloading ${i}"
        cat ${i}.fasta >> muscle_input.fasta
        rm ${i}.fasta
    done
```

to confirm, the weblinks that I create using this script are all valid so they open up the sequence data I require when I click the weblinks.

Comment: `I have a script` Please _show_ the script. `when I use the wget command` How do you use it?

Comment: sorry, new to this.. added the script if you are able to help?

Comment: can you also show content of `uniprot_id.txt`?

Comment: Hi, I’ve resolved the issue now! Something to do with the default SSL configuration being too strict

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble with this. Would you be able to share what changes you made to the SSL configuration please?

In the meantime, because I trust the URL domain, I was able to workaround the issue with this line:

```
wget ${URL}${i}.fasta --no-check-certificate
```

I think I need to update domain certificates somewhere, but I'm working on that.